# New boarding pass after flight time change?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

My flight time has changed, do I need to get new boarding pass ?

Answer (score 1):

No, not unless the flight number, destination, seat or flight date has also changed.

If your boarding pass is no longer valid it will be fixed when you get on the plane.

Comment: I hope that it would actually be fixed *before* you get on the plane.